# Mongo DB Aggregations

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to generate data for a heat map on my dashboard. I need to group the data by days i.e Monday, Tuesday e.t.c and then group the data by time intervals. I am able to group the data by days. But the time interval part doesnt work. I am using MongoDB.

Sample of my Schema is shown below

```
{
    "createdAt": "2020-06-30T22:47:32+00:00",
    "day": "Wednesday",
    "user": {
        "$oid": "5ec51d59ddfb380017649591"
    },
    "country": "NG",
    "city": "",
    "userType": "superadmin",
    "fullName": "Jane Doe",
    "__v": 0
}
```

This is what I could come up with so far

```
      let heatMap = await await Session.aggregate([
        {
          $group: {
            _id: "$day",
            count: { $sum: 1 },
          },
        },
      ]);
```

This groups by day for me already.
I need to further group by intervals of  hours

Sample Expected Data

```
    [
        {
          _id: "Sunday",
          intervals: [
            {
              interval1: "12am-6am",
              count: 34,
            },
            {
              interval2: "6am-12noon",
              count: 44,
            },
          ],
        },
        {
          _id: "Monday",
          intervals: [
            {
              interval1: "12am-6am",
              count: 34,
            },
            {
              interval2: "6am-12noon",
              count: 44,
            },
          ],
        },
      ];
```

Comment: Please post your aggregation pipeline

Comment: what intervals do you want?

Comment: @TomSlabbaert intervals of 6 hours

Comment: Also what Mongo version are you using?

Comment: Can you also post a sample expected output?

Comment: @hhharsha36
Question Updated

Comment: @TomSlabbaert Version 4.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this pipeline that utilizes [$mod](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/mod/) with some date operators to achieve the result you want.

The strategy is first to group by the intervals and the finally by the day of the week as this simplifies the process.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        "$toDate": {
          "$subtract": [
            {
              "$toLong": {
                $toDate: "$createdAt"
              }
            },
            {
              "$mod": [
                {
                  "$toLong": {
                    $toDate: "$createdAt"
                  }
                },
                21600000
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      count: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        day: {
          $dayOfWeek: "$_id"
        },
        hour: {
          $hour: "$_id"
        }
      },
      count: {
        $sum: "$count"
      },
      interval: {
        $first: "$_id"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id.day",
      intervals: {
        $push: {
          count: "$count",
          interval: "$interval"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Notice that the result is not exactly how you want, i.e `_id: 3` is equal to `_id: "Tuesday"` As Mongo does not provide any out of the box conversions you'll have to do it yourself either in code or by using something like [$switch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/switch/)

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/arjtM0QM5lr)

Comment: This generates the data in intervals. But I get 6 intervals instead of 4. I dont think that should be possible because we are running 6 hour intervals and that should yield 4 intervals

Comment: They are not from the same date then, it is not possible https://mongoplayground.net/p/BtOtjQgvM83

Comment: Yes, I wanna group them based on the day and not the date.
So every entry on a Tuesday should be together irrespective of the date

Comment: This is what's happening here. as you can see here: https://mongoplayground.net/p/VKWSL_hhM99 we have documents from the 23rd and from the 30th (i.e same day of the week) and they span over all the hours in the day and we get 4 intervals. if you want to share your exact data i might be able to help but the pipeline is working as required.

Comment: The data sets are quite similar, i guess the only difference is that i have a day property in my schema.
https://mongoplayground.net/p/v3NU6UBtWJs

Comment: mb you were right and i got confused, i edited my answer to match what you want.